# Get all document libraries from a site URL

Tags: client-object-model, spweb

I'm trying to build a WPF application in which the user specifies the URL in a textbox and after clicking "Connect" the app will fill a Combobox with a list of SharePoint Document Libraries. I'm failing at finding the solution for that functionality, does anybody have any examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rest api of sharepoint. See [this post](http://sharepointsabrine.wordpress.com/2012/02/14/using-rest-api-to-access-a-sharepoint-list/) to understand how to use it in your case. Also you can use sharepoint [client object model](http://debugmode.net/2011/01/30/fetching-lists-from-sharepoint-2010-site-using-client-object-model/).